# binding class method to thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, bind

Look at the following snipet:

```
struct Event
{
    void event1( time_t t );
    void event2( int, int );
}

Event* f = ...;

time_t t; int i1, int i2;

// 1st
std::thread t{ std::bind( &Event::event1, f, std::placeholders::_1 ), t };
std::thread t{ std::bind( &Event::event2, f, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2 ), i1, i2 };

// 2nd method
std::thread t{ &Event::event1, f, t };
std::thread t{ &Event::event2, f, i1, i2 };
```

Which is the difference between 1st and 2nd method. Which method is better?

Comment: `std::bind` is not needed here, for a discussion see the answer in the question I linked. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10673612/893693

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method creates a call wrapper around the functions, their `Event` instances and their respective arguments using `std::bind`. It then passes these call wrappers to the thread object.

The second method passes the functions, `Event` instances and arguments directly to the thread objects.

The result of both methods will be the same, although the first method seems to perform an unneccessary step to me.

Use `std::bind` when you need to pass around a wrapper instead of the individual parameters, e.g:

```
auto func = std::bind(&Event::event1, f, std::placeholders::_1);

functionTakingCallable(func);
functionTakingCallable2(func);
std::thread t(func, arg);
```